# Trying to use MadgwickAHRS python script, but can't retrieve the new calculated data

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I want to use madgwick's AHRS filter. I'm trying to use the translated Python code (Jonas Boër, 2015) but I can't get it to work properly. The script can be found here  https://github.com/morgil/madgwick_py

I'm having trouble understanding the use of classes. Below is a script were I first import the class which is stated in madgwickahrs.py. Second I define 1 frame of random data for the gyroscope, accelerometer and magnetometer.
After this I initialize the class and call the different functions inside the class. (note: with the normal array of data I should put this in a loop to calculate the new list of quaternions for each frame)

```
import numpy as np
from madgwickahrs import MadgwickAHRS

gyr = np.array( [1.6, 0.6, 1.5])
acc = np.array( [1.2, 1.9, 1.3])
mag = np.array( [2.1, 1.3, 2.1])
gyr_rad = gyr * (np.pi/180)

new_data = MadgwickAHRS() 
# No parameters filled in means it will use the parameters stated 
in the script (sampleperiod = 1/256, quaternion = [1 0 0 0], beta = 1)

new_data.update(gyr_rad,acc,mag)
new_data.update_imu(gyr_rad,acc)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the calculated new quaternions and preferably asign it to a new variable so I can use it for the rest of the script.

Hope I made my self clear and someone can help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me the following method worked:

```
heading = MadgwickAHRS()
        while True:
            ninedofxyz = self._ninedof.read()
            heading.update(ninedofxyz[0], ninedofxyz[2], ninedofxyz[1])
            ahrs = heading.quaternion.to_euler_angles()
            roll = ahrs[0]
            pitch = ahrs[1]
            yaw = ahrs[2]
```

More info is given here: https://github.com/morgil/madgwick_py/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

The [MadgwickAHRS](https://github.com/morgil/madgwick_py) also has the [Quaternion](https://github.com/morgil/madgwick_py/blob/master/quaternion.py) class implementation which contains the `get_q()` for retrieving the new quaternion values.

```
new_data.quaternion.get_q()
```